# Where can I legally stream or download Ninku?

Tags: ninku

I want to know details about Ninku. It's a very old ninja anime. Anybody knows from where I can legally get raw or subbed links or online streams or even a manga?
When I was little, a TV channel named "Animax" used to telecast episodes of Ninku. This was about 10-12 year ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are DVDs available, if you keep an eye out. Here's [one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Ninku-Japanese-DVD-BOX-Complete-Set-TV-Anime-/281361514972) ...at 750$ :(

The manga seems to only have been published in [French](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=3275)

It doesn't look like its been touched by any English groups apart from the original broadcast so I'm afraid you're out of luck.

[ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=2603) doesn't mention any Japanese streaming download sites, so I think your best bet is to try and get the DVDs somewhere and import the manga if you read Japanese.